# Issue while copying data from local to S3 to Redshift table

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-redshift

I have written a program which generates data in csv format, then uploads that data to S3 which eventually gets copies to Redshift table. Here is the code

```
bucket2 = self.s3Conn.lookup('my-bucket')
    k = Key(bucket2)

    ## Delete existing
    key_del = bucket2.delete_key("test_file.csv")

    ## Create new key and upload file to s3
    k.Key = "test_file.csv"
    k.name = "test_file.csv"
    k.set_contents_from_filename('test_file.csv')

    ## Move file from S3 to redshift

    logging.info("\nFile Uploaded to S3 bucket\n")

    try:

        self.newCur.execute("Truncate test_file")

        self.newCur.execute("COPY test_file FROM 's3://my-bucket/test_file.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx DELIMITER ','; ")

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        logging.exception("Database exception ")
```

File has around 13500 lines with 10 columns.
I verified that redhshift has same number of columns and data type

But still, everytime it breaks after 13204 line with error in "stl_load_errors" table as "Delimited not found". Data in row 13204 doesnt matter as I updated that row also with other values.

So I check S3 bucket to check my csv file. I downloaded file which was copied to S3 bucket. What I see is that file is not copied entirely. It usually breaks around 811007 characters.

Earlier I have uploaded larger files into S3 without any issue.

Any idea as why is this happening?

Comment: Some random ideas: Update boto to latest version (`sudo pip install boto --upgrade`), is it related to the line count or more the file length?, were the bigger files you uploaded done with the same code?, when you call set_contents_from_filename it returns the number of bytes written -- do they match your expected size or the size of the actual file created?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help. The issue was pretty simple.

I was writing the file on my local disk using `file.write()` and then copying it to S3.
So before copying to S3, I needed to CLOSE the file using `file.close()`, which I did not do.

Yes, that's silly :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look closer if there are NULL bytes 0x00 at row 13204.  I have seen those in the middle of fields which cause different kinds of loading errors.  To check, you can either use NULL AS '\000' option to bypass them or use a hex editor to read the file.  Note that a normal editor might not show there's a null byte.

Answer (score 0):

I take similar approach in my Redshift CSV upload script.
You can use it to do "sanity check" or draw performance baseline for the script you are working on.

Try [CSV_Loader_For_Redshift](https://github.com/alexbuz/CSV_Loader_For_Redshift).

Script will:

- Compress and upload your file to S3
- Append your data to Redshift table.

Sample output for 12Mb/50k line file:

```
S3        | data.csv.gz | 100% 
Redshift  | test2       | DONE 
Time elapsed: 5.7 seconds
```